# Moving a function from Controller to Service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function

I have the following in my Controller:

```
    $scope.getParameterByName = function (name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    };
```

and in my HTML:

```
{{getParameterByName('test')}}
```

I'd like to move the function into a service to reuse this piece of code across other controllers.

I moved the function into a controller and renamed `$scope.getParameterByName` to `this.getParameterByName`

I made sure to inject the module and service into my controller.

In my controller I added the following code:

```
$scope.getParameterByName = function (name) {
    newService.getParameterByName(name);
};
```

However, now the expression in my HTML does not render the result. If I add the following to my service:

`console.log(results[1]);`

it is logging the correct result. What am I missing in my controller/HTML to render the expression properly again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to return the result value from your method.

```
$scope.getParameterByName = function (name) {
    return newService.getParameterByName(name);
};
```

More elegant solution would be just bind the reference of service method to scope variable

```
$scope.getParameterByName = newService.getParameterByName; //referenced service method
```

Comment: Thanks! great suggestion about the alternate solution, much better.

Comment: Glad to hel you..Thanks :)